# CMake interpret string as variable

Tags: cmake

I'm looking for a way to interpret a string as variable name in cmake.

Given:

```
set(MY_SECRET_VAR "foo")

# later only the name of the variable is known.
set(THE_NAME "MY_SECRET_VAR")

# Now i'm looking for a way to get the value "foo" from the name
# something like:
set(THE_VALUE "${THE_NAME}")

# THE_VALUE should be "foo"
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A second level of unwrapping:

```
set(THE_VALUE "${${THE_NAME}}")
```