# Expand variable name containing a generator expression in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

In the build process, I set directories where I gather the build output of different sub-projects. The directories are set as :

```
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../build/bin/debug" )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../build/bin/release" )
```

Now, I'd like to copy some files (a directory of qt plugins) to that directory dependent on the configuration which it is built for.

I tried:

```
    # copy qt plugins 
    add_custom_command( TARGET mytarget POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                        "${QT_DIR}/../../../plugins"
                        "${$<UPPER_CASE:CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_$<CONFIG> >}/plugins"
                    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

thus, I try to build a string that equals the variable name and then try to expand that as described here: [CMake interpret string as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631168/cmake-interpret-string-as-variable). In other words: I would like to have a generator expression that evaluates to the content of `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` or `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTOR_RELEASE` dependent on the current build configuration.

However running cmake with the statement above results in an error:
`"CMakeLists.txt:112: error: Syntax error in cmake code at [..] when parsing string ${$<UPPER_CASE:CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_$<CONFIG> >}/plugins Invalid character ('<') in a variable name: '$'`

So my question is, how can I use a generator-expression to access the corresponding variable? (Bonus question: is there another/better way to achieve the same goal?)

Comment: Did you try [`$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:tgt,expr>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_GENEX_EVAL)? It would seem like something that might help.

Comment: @ixSci from the linked documentation, it might be a lead, but I don't understand how I would transfer this to my issue - could you elaborate?

Comment: I haven't used that particular genex, it was just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, how can I use a generator-expression to access the corresponding variable?

You cannot. There is currently (CMake <=3.23) no way to expand a variable whose name is determined by the value of a generator expression.

> Bonus question: is there another/better way to achieve the same goal?

Yes, and you are almost there! You can use `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:...>`:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET mytarget POST_BUILD
  COMMAND
  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
  "${QT_DIR}/../../../plugins"
  "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mytarget>/plugins"
  VERBATIM
)
```

This works because `TARGET_FILE_DIR` evaluates to the actual directory containing the executable or library file for `mytarget`, no matter the active configuration, property values, etc.

Docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_FILE_DIR

---

`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>` is already relative to the binary directory so you should *not* try to compute the binary directory in its definition. Also, it supports generator expressions. Thus, the following will be **much** more robust:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "bin/$<LOWER_CASE:$<CONFIG>>"
    CACHE STRING "Common output directory for runtime artifacts")
```

This has a bunch of concrete benefits:

1. No need to set `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` or `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE`
2. This will work for `MinSizeRel` and `RelWithDebInfo`, plus any custom configurations one might add down the line.
3. Since it's defined as a cache variable, it can be overridden for debugging / working around name clashes, etc.

A bit more context for (3): *most* `CMAKE_*` variables are *intended* to be either read-only or user-configurable (i.e. at the command line, from the GUI, etc.). Overriding their defaults via `set(CACHE)` is a polite compromise. A notable exception to this rule is the collection of Qt codegen flags (`CMAKE_AUTO{MOC,RCC,UIC}`). These must typically be set for the build to produce usable binaries.